# Node.js with socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am looking to build an web application using node.js and possibly socket.io but I am having a lots of confusion regarding whether to use socket.io or go with plain http. In the app the node.js server will be basically an api server which serves json to the javascript client or may be mobile clients too. The web app will also has chat messeneger for its users, this is where socket.io comes in.

- I am not sure whether to use socket.io for the whole app or only for the chat part. Although my app itself could benefit from socket.io but its nothing that I think can't be done using plain http and client making more requests to the server.
- I have read at several places that sometimes socket.io can be difficult to scale for more users.
- Socket.io often crashes and specially creates probs when there are firewall in clients system.
- More importantly.....I checked out socket.io user list and did not find many users, so was curious to know what kind of platform is more know chat network like facebook messenger, google talk etc are built upon, Are any built using http-ajax and continues querying to the server.

Please help me out in solving this question. Some might argue that this is a opinion based question. But what actually I am trying to figure out the implementation of socket.io and its limitation.

Comment: Socket.io doesn't force you to use websocket. Websockets make you app realtime, you can use any other supported ways of transports ,jsonp,etc..

Comment: @GeoPhoenix Yeah I understand that but I am talking here about socket.io and plain http. The comparison is between them only

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest serving your API over HTTP and leave the real-time business to Socket.io. If you are adverse to using Websockets, like @GeoPheonix stated, you can choose from a variety of transport methods using both socket.io and sockjs (https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-node).

As far as scaling is concerned, I deployed a socket.io based real-time analytics/tracking service for a very large application with ana average of 400+ concurrent connections with no visible performance impact, but this may depend on the implementation and hardware.

Answer (score 0):

- Socket.io is faster than plain http. I recommend you to use it for all since you have to have a chat in first place.
- In my case, real-time Texas Hold'em-like game can receive up to 2500 concurrent with one node process. However, if you change transport from websocket to xhr-polling, It can receive like more 10x than pure websocket. Your application is just chat so, I guess a little slow down wouldn't be a problem. If you sure you will exceed this number, yes, scale socket.io is a pain.
- This problem will happen only if you open socket.io for port other than 80 and 443. If you have frontend web server with other language already, you can still use socket.io on another subdomain to be able to run on port 80 without conflict with your main frontend web server. Socket.io support cross-domain without a problem.
- Have you used trello.com? If not, try it :). It's best for task management or even some Agile thing. They used socket.io. https://c9.io/ is another one. It's online IDE with google doc-like collaborative. One thing to note is xhr-polling trasport in socket.io is the same with http-ajax with long-polling (Better than general ajax). You can read more info at:
  http://book.mixu.net/node/ch13.html